# JMeter save listener configuration as xml not working

Tags: jmeter

I try to save the output file of a listener (doesn't seem to matter which kind of listener, but I try the 'View Results Tree' listener) as xml. I can check the 'Save as Xml' flag, and when I then run the jmeter plan, without closing the gui, I get an xml output. As soon as I close the gui and I try again the output changes to csv, but in the jmx file itself there is still an xml element true for that ResultCollector. I have the same issue when I run headless.

I tried changing the jmeter.properties to

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

and that seems to do the trick, but that would likely mean that I cannot output csv format anymore. Is the 'Save as xml' broken? I've got this with jmeter 2.11 r1554548, which seems to be the last stable one from the site of apache.

I suppose this isn't expected behaviour? Anybody experienced something similar? I can reproduce this from scratch, consistently.

Kasper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug was introduced in the later versions of JMeter where a line was no longer being saved into the jmx file.

Old versions has this in the listener section of the file (Ver. < 2.9)

```
    <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
```

Newer versions do not have that line (Ver. 2.10 and 2.11 I've confirmed)

```
    <objProp>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
```

I pasted that missing line into my file and 2.11 loaded properly with 'Save as XML' checked this time.

Might want to open an official bug report on this issue and reference this question in it.

Comment: That was it, only tested with 2.10 and 2.11 so I thought I was doing it wrong. Bug report filed, must be a very underused feature to slip through two versions.

Comment: A year later and I just discovered that this bug is still there in the latest release. I can't find a bug for it in the project tracker, was one filed?